# Brightness keeps changing in Windows 10 x64

Tags: windows-10, brightness

I have tried everything, going to advanced power settings, system settings but nothing. I have also tried to go to Intel options but i don't see any option to turn off power saving so I don't know what to do. It changes when im swapping windows, for example, if I am on Facebook and I swap to a game window, it decreases in brightness.

Comment: I didn't even know brightness can change in a desktop computer. Laptops, sure, but a desktop?

Comment: im not using a desktop xD

Comment: Your question says "desktop-computer".

Comment: my bad new to this website.

Comment: What is the model of your laptop? What do you mean by "brightness change"? Does it changes according to ambient light conditions / battery level? Does it change when you leave your laptop idle for a few minutes? Please add these to your question (don't answer in a comment) to help us understand your issue.

Comment: I have seen this behavior when I am NOT plugged in and using battery power. It reduces brightness when showing dark images (or windows) and increases brightness when showing very light images. But when I am plugged in, the brightness won't change when switching between dark and light images.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This was bugging me for years till I found answer in some obscure forum, here it the problem: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3046889/intel-display-power-saving-technology-settings-incorrect-if-power-source-changed-during-sleep

In case the link drops dead, here is still solution how to fix it

**Solution**

- Open your Intel HD

  - The drivers for your integrated Intel HD graphics card. I am aware this is counter intuitive for users who have dedicated graphics card, but the way this whole thing at point of writing is working means that most settings from here are considered 'master' settings.
- Make sure that under `battery` you have the power saving option disabled.

  - Yes, I know that you might be thinking what kind of hard liquor I was drinking, but trust me, this setting is still in affect when you plug in your laptop into the wall.
  - Make sure to check this from time to time, because I found out that this options get reactivated on updates and some other random triggers.
- If you notice that your screen is still flickering brightens based on background, just unplug the power cable and plug it back it. This will reset some DPST settings and it will stop doing it. This happens only if you use sleep on your laptop. Full shutdown should be fine.

**Edit October 2021**
Some laptops these days come with advanced optimus or MUX switch to allow laptops to use dedicated GPU only. One example is Razer. If you switch the mode to use the dedicated GPU and open Intel HD then these battery options might not be visible, so you have to turn off this mode, restart your laptop, flip the setting, then enable back dedicated GPU only.

Annoying thing is that dimming occurs even with dedicated mode and it resets settings for me each time there is windows update even if I don't use integrated GPU at all.

Comment: oh my god thank you so much. such a simple solution and it worked!! :) thanks

Comment: Thanks for the addition, I noticed that it flickers when the windows displayed are changing. Your fix by replugging the power adapter worked. Thanks!

Comment: This was bugging me for over a year... Was so frustrating... Then I bought new laptop (this wasn't the only reason for it) and same thing was happening, I almost lost my sanity there :D

Comment: This solved my problem.  For me, the screen was using some kind of auto-contrast adjustment, which caused light screens (like web pages) to become much brighter, while dark screens (like many apps with grey backgrounds) would become much darker.

Comment: The last step saved me some time. I already had done the others but it was still changing the brightness. Thanks @MiroslavSaracevic

Comment: Wow I cannot believe the unplug/plug-back-in thing worked, that is amazing. This laptop drives me crazy, I cannot believe how bad this Intel HD card is.

Comment: Wow, I remember having this bein a problem back in 2013, can't believe it's 2021 and it is still an issue :D

Answer (score 7):

The other answers didn't work for me - here's how I fixed it:

1. From your desktop, click the **Intel Graphics Settings** icon in the bottom right-hand corner.
2. Then from the Intel Graphics Settings dashboard, click on the **Power** icon.
3. Tick **Disable** under **Display Power Saving Technology**.

This is taken [from the Reddit source](https://www.reddit.com/r/Huawei/comments/8lv6zy/matebook_x_pro_adaptive_brightness/).

Comment: I find it amusing that reddit source links back to this threads accepted answer as source :D

Comment: The option isn't there

Comment: Some more solutions that have worked for me on different laptops, notably LG Grams of different years, (1) disable DPST via registry or this cmd https://github.com/orev/dpst-control   (2) LG software would lower brightness on boot, I disabled all LG Bloatware from Task Manager > Startup

Answer (score 6):

Turning off `Display Power Savings` in Intel® Graphics Command Center fixed the issue for me.

[image: Display Power Savings in Intel® Graphics Command Center]

or in a new design

[image: Display Power Savings in Intel® Graphics Command Center New]

Comment: YES, thank you so much! Nothing else worked. Now there are no more annoying screen brightness changes on battery!

Answer (score 3):

I believe it's called 'adaptive brightness' and it's under the power settings advanced options.

[image]

Comment: i tried that. Its on off and it still changes

Comment: You said you've tried looking in the Intel Display settings.. when it asked for basic/ advanced settings did you click basic? I'm sure there are power settings in there? :/

Comment: there's no advanced settings in power :/

Comment: Windows 10? See the link attached.. I see no reason there wouldn't be? confuuused. https://s32.postimg.org/hfivk1ulh/Battery_Saver_Windows_10_Enable_or_Disable_Pictu.png

Answer (score 3):

Late in the day, but I've just been entertained by this problem.  After reviewing quite a few posts, none of which fixed the issue for me, I noticed that -

1. Right click on desktop, select Graphics Properties
2. Select Display
3. Changed Refresh Rate from 40hz to 60hz and Saved the profile

Fixed the issue with Windows 10 contrast issue instantly for me on a Dell M4700 Precision.

Hope this helps folks.

Answer (score 2):

I did not have the display power settings option in the Intel® Graphics Command Center on my Dell G3 3590.

What worked for me:

Go into your Bios settings (for my Dell laptop press F12 while booting) > go into video settings and disable the dynamic back light control.

Answer (score 1):

What I did was simply go to Display in the Settings application and unticked "Change brightness automatically when lighting changes". It should be on the top of the menu.

Answer (score 1):

#### For Windows Surface users

### OR

For those who don't have **Intel® Graphics Command Center** OR `Adaptative brightness` in **Power Manager**, you can download Intel® Graphics Command Center from **Microsoft Store** (just write Intel Graphics Command).

Open Intel CMD Center you downloaded from MS Store, go to `System` menu (left panel), then `Power` and turn off:

- Adaptative brightness
- Display Power Saving
- Enhanced Power Saving

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with a Lenovo Thinkpad P1 Gen2 under W10PRro version 2004. Only a few options were available and none for turning on/off the adaptative brightness.

However, turning off the HDR mode seems to solve this issue.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that if you download/already have Intel Graphics Command Centre, you can go into 'System' then from there go into 'power'. And if 'adaptive brightness' is on, turn it off, however, for me it was already turned off, so go down and turn:

- display power savings: off

Now you shouldn't have that issue where your screen will automatically change brightness when it goes from dark to light images.

Answer (score 0):

The answers here helped me to figure out how to do it for my Laptop (Acer Nitro AN515). I do not have the Power Setting "Adaptive Brightness" and I also do not have anything from Intel.

In my case, I had to go to Start Menu, **AMD Radeon Settings Lite** and there to Display and change Vari-Bright to Off (see screenshots below).

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem on my workstation, display kept on switching brightness based on what was on the screen. But it had nothing to do with Windows 10 og Intel HD. Rather, a peculiar setting on the monitor itself was causing the problem. For some reason a setting called "Dynamic contrast" was enabled. I disabled it via the menu system on my LCD display monitor and problem was solved!